# Tab is shown inspite of ngIf

Tags: html, angular, tabs, angular-ng-if

The FirstTab still remains inspite of using ngIf. ngIf helps in not rendering the selector first-tab.How to remove the tab also.

here's the code

```html
<tabs style="min-height:auto">
        <tab tabTitle="FirstTab" *ngIf="str=='dp'" >
            <first-tab></first-tab>
        </tab>
        <tab tabTitle="SecondTab" [active]="true">
            <second-tab>
            </second-tab>
        </tab>
</tabs>
```

*dp* is one of the options  from the dropdown(*whose code is not shown*)

when dp is chosen

this is rendered on the browser [two tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QktnK.jpg)

when other options is chosen

this is rendered on the browser [two tabs with first tab disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9pLi.jpg)

**now cannot i remove the tab altogether when str!=dp ?**

Also when i again choose Dp 
then this is rendered [one more first Tab is inserted that is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsfcn.jpg) 
The *ngIf expression works fine ...surely
I have used [hidden] and ngshow
**How to resolve this ?**

Comment: Yes you can. If `*ngIf` resolves to false, component will not render at all (will be removed from DOM).
But I didn't get the third case, why it got repeated?

Comment: Yes ngIf resolves to false if other options are selected. ngIf effects on the selector and not the whole tab

Comment: Check the value, is it 'DP' or 'Dp' or 'dp' ? and put "===" instead of "=="

Comment: it is dp and i have tried '==='

Comment: Check if [hidden]="str!=='dp'" works

Comment: I have used hidden and ngshow ,but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using `angularjs` and not `Angular 2+`. Maybe you should try with ng-if instead of *ngIf

Here is the documentation for your version of `angularjs`. 
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: It was a stackoverflow **Snippet** feature that allows you to select additional libraries. Akash chose AngularJS by mistake (similar to Angular), when he was making his Snippet (_the latest version in there is 1.2.23 by the way_).